# Why can't I check for a r-value-reference with a requires-constraint?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
    requires is_rvalue_reference_v<T>
void f( T &&v )
{
    T v2( forward<T>( v ) );
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << v2 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string str = "hello world";
    f( move( str ) );
}
```

Why does this not compile until I remove the requires clause or: why doesn't the compiler notice that T is r-value-reference ?

Comment: But `T` *isn't* an r-value reference. It's just plain `std::string`. Otherwise the argument would be a `std::string&& &&` which doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 7):

As [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), when being passed rvalue `T` will be deduced as a non-reference type. For `f( move( str ) );`, `T` will be `std::string` (and the type of function parameter `v` will be `std::string&&`).

You can change the condition to:

```
template<typename T>
    requires is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>
//                                  ^^
void f( T &&v )
{
    T v2( forward<T>( v ) );
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << v2 << endl;
}
```

For additional information, when being passed lvalue `T` will be deduced as lvalue-reference type. E.g. for `f(str);` `T` will be deduced as `std::string&` and `T&&` leads to `std::string&` too.